# When using expect: SSHFS Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: bash, expect, sshfs

When I run my SSHFS connection script from bash, everything works perfectly.

However, when I run the same script using the `expect` utility, I get the following error when I try to access the folder mount location:

```
Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Here is my expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn standard_sshfs_connection_string_or_script
expect "password: "
send "my_password\r"
```

**Q:** Any Ideas?

Note:

1. I've first already called: `fusermount -u mount_location`
2. Is there something about `spawn` creating a new process, perhaps the sshfs process closes prematurely? (Is there any way to ensure the sshfs process stays open?)

Comment: Does your standard_sshfs_connection_string_or_script make use of absolute paths, or are you using relative ones?

Comment: uses absolute paths :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the output of `sshfs` is caught in `expect`. This may be your problem - the script terminates without sending the password, which would cause the problem you describe.

Another possible scenario is that `sshfs` is actually sending you the output `user@domain password:`, and expect may not like it.

However, this really isn't a good way of dealing with the problem. Your password is in plain text within that script!!

Have you considered using public-key authentication? Take a look at [this git example](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) if you don't know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but perhaps I need to have the following line after the `send` command:

`expect "$ "`

to wait for the program to fully exit.

Another idea: perhaps when expect exits/closes, all of the child processes also terminate?